# How to open another activity without lose item on main activity layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

i have two empty activity name main activity and another activity. Both of them has different contents. On main activity layout, i have a button and a banner ads. And on my another activity layout i have a imageview that fill up the layout width and height.

My question is, how can i display the content page at another layout replace with my content page on main layout. So i will not put the ads inside the another activity layout again and write the admob java code again inside the java class.

Main activity xml layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

     //start content page//
    <Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
      android:id="@+id/button/>
      //end content page//


    //the ads
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height"wrap_content"
        android:alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Another activity xml layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    //content pages
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height"match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/pict_two"/>
    //content pages


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please, tag Android too.

Comment: consider using of [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) for such behavior

Comment: @DmitryArc based my question which one should i do. FrameLayout or fragments?

Comment: @DmitryArc is this same?

Comment: @user9056633, you have 2 different options to get what you want:
1. You can have 1 Activity with any child of ViewGroup in your xml to show content and Banner separately. The content will be implemented in Fragments.
2. You can have 2 Activities (each with ViewGroup) with content and use Fragment to share advertising logic

Comment: @DmitryArc i want have 2 activities for each layout. So i can do another things with the java class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use Fragments and in case you want swipeable views try to play around with ViewPager so that the user can navigate to the both the views by just swiping the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ViewGroup with Fragment activities.

Checkout the API reference 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html